# Is there a complete overview and classification of all Probabilistic Neuronal Codes (PPC)?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, neurophysiology

I am trying to gather an explicit and complete overview of so-called Probabilistic Neuronal Codes (PPC). I have found various PPC models from literature, but have difficulties having them classified, and being certain that the collection is also physiological relevant (not only mathematical/hypothetical playground) and complete.

[Friston 2009](https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S136466130900117X), Table 2, is already 14 years old and yet, my ultimate source, but the classification over there is not very comprehensive.

My question:

- May you provide with more recent investigations, where all neurophysiological relevant PPCs were gathered, compared and classified in mathematical and physiological well explained and comprehensive way?
- Whether you may have an own proposal for such a collection and classification?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The table you reference seems fairly comprehensive to me, though consider that all of those equations are tweakable. Like George Box said, "all models are wrong, some are useful" - these models are all certainly wrong, but may be useful.

Comment: And I am aking what is pro and what contra for each, and whther complete. This is why I believe the list and the paragraph about it is not comprehensive. There is newer articles that only focus on log ang logit forms as realistic.

Comment: That seems like a project far beyond the scope of a stack exchange Q and A.